# InputNumber built-in forms component read only in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

How can I make readonly InputNumber, built-in forms component in Blazor?

Comment: Finaly i got the answer, MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters. <InputNumber @bind-Value="item.OnBalanceVolume" readonly="true"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it by adding the `readonly` attribute like this:

```
 <InputNumber readonly Id="name" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Model.NumberSelection" />
```